# dataset flatmap groupBy missing parameter type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset with a column that contains a List of numbers.

I want to count the occurrences of every single number in all of these lists. So I do a flatMap, to get a set of all the integers. I want to group it so I have each number only once and then add the number of occurrences (in a second column or something).
My code so far:

```
val counts = dataset.flatMap(_.intLists).groupBy(i => identity(i)).count
```

But it always says, that "i" is missing the parameter type. I guess I need to tell that it is a Int, but how do i do that? Or am I missing something completely different?

Comment: You can just do `.groupBy(identity)`.

Comment: if I do that, I get the error 'missing argument list for method identity in object Predef Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing identity _ or identity(_) instead of identity.'

Comment: Weird. Works fine for me. What type is `dataset`? Anyways, you can specify the type of `i` by writing `(i: Int) => identity(i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing your code with a Spark 2.0.2 dependency in the classpath, I see that the `groupBy` method expects either a `String` or a `Column`.

You may want to use the `groupByKey` method that takes a function to extract the grouping key (in your example, `identity`).

```
val counts = dataset.flatMap(_.intLists).groupByKey(identity).count
```

Comment: Thanks. That was almoust too easy :-) I got it working both ways, groupBy("value") and groupByKey(identity).